# "Metro Line" diagrams in Latex, what is best approach?

Tags: latex, diagram

How does one goes at trying to render such diagram with Latex.

Europe’s many alliances, reimagined as a Metro system European 
countries are bound together in many ways 
https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/world/how-european-countries-are-bound-together/?noredirect=on

Is there a package for such type of "Metro Line" diagrams ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following tikz code could be a starting point:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (Norway) at (0,1);
\coordinate (Belgium) at (2,0);

\draw[ultra thick, red] (Norway) -- (1:0.9599) -- (Belgium);
\draw[ultra thick, blue] ($(Norway) + (0,-0.1)$) --   ($(1:0.9599) + (-0.03,-0.065)$) -- ($(Belgium) + (0,-0.065)$);

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] at (Norway) {Norway};
\draw[fill=white] (Norway) circle (0.03);
\draw[fill=white] ($(Norway) + (0,-0.1)$) circle (0.03);

\node[rotate=45,anchor=west] at (Belgium) {Belgium};
\draw[fill=white] (Belgium) circle (0.03);
\draw[fill=white] ($(Belgium) + (0,-0.065)$) circle (0.03);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using a Windows 7, 64-bit with Miktex but it does not generate the image you provided. I change the typo "ate" to "at" but I get the "way" of Norway at 45 degree ... do I need to specify the origins of the tikz space ? is tikz only happy when generating PDF and not DVI ?

Comment: @bhamadicharef This should work even with the typo. How exactly are you compiling the document? And which version of tikz do you have?

Comment: A recent article "Experiments in Constraint-based Graphic Design" by Anish Athalye at https://www.anishathalye.com/2019/12/12/constraint-based-graphic-design/ is actually close to what I wanted to do ...